# Iteration to prove solution to difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Use iteration to show that the solution to the difference equation $x_{t+1}= \lambda x_t +p_t $ can be written 
$$x_t=x_0 \lambda^t + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{t-1} p_k \lambda^{t-k-1} $$
Here $p_t$ is a fixed sequence of values

Proof
So I started with 
$$x_1 = \lambda x_0 +p_0$$
$$x_2 = \lambda (\lambda x_0 +p_0)+p_1$$
$$x_3 = \lambda (\lambda^2 x_0 +\lambda p_0+p_1)+p_2$$

Can I just now make a table saying the relationship between $k$ and $t$?

Comment: I think you should use induction if you want to show it strictly.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the recursion by $λ^{-t-1}$ and set $y_t=λ^{-t}x_t$ and $q_t=λ^{-t-1}p_t$  to get
$$
λ^{-t-1}x_{t+1}=λ^{-t}x_t+λ^{-t-1}p_t\implies y_{t+1}=y_t+q_t
$$
The last is the recursion formula for a multiple sum,
$$
y_{t}=y_0+\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}q_k
$$
Resolving the substitutions backwards will give your result.

Comment: is this induction or iteration?

Comment: This is hiding the induction in the one for a most basic identity, in this case the one for the arithmetic progression.